# Alternative to android setRotationY?

Tags: android, animation

There is any method to replace View.setRotationY(float)? I need the same effect of setRotationY. I tried with Matrix, but the efect is not the same.
I need this effect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nine old droids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library.

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotationY", 0, 180),
```